# C# pass parameter from ajax call to class

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have an ajax call like so:

```
var is_where = true;

$.get("/api/airport/getListItems", { where: is_where}, function (data) {

});
```

And I am trying to pass it here:

```
public class AirportClass{

     public List<AirportClass> getListItems(string where = null){
     }

}
```

and I put a break point on my public List and where is still equal null when I am expecting true, am i passing this in wrong? if so, how would I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to specify the content type as JSON (as Ive seen from my experience)

```
var is_where = true;
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/api/airport/getListItems',
    data: is_where,
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {

    }
});
```

The Value your passing is Bool, pls change your method signature to :

```
public class AirportClass{

     public List<AirportClass> getListItems(bool where){
     }

}
```

Comment: bool where gave me an error (No overload for method 'getListItems' tkaes 0 arguments), so I put bool where = false, but it still does not change to true

Comment: can you try string instead of bool in C#

Comment: sure you can do that!

Comment: You need to pass the parameter when you are calling the method, for example,url: '/api/airport/getListItems' + is_where, (data can be {} in this case). However, i have noticed as per convention you are looking for GET method instead of POST.